# How to fetch the variable value in service now when ordering item from service catalog?

Tags: servicenow, rest

I have successfully ordered an item from service catalog using **REST API**. While ordering I sent a **JSON data** in the request body containing certain ***key value*** pairs which are meant to be stored in variable of the catalog item. After the successful order, the response generated contains the ***sys_id***, ***request_number, request_id, table name***. Now, when I want to fetch the values passed to variables, the only way available is to make a **GET** call using the **REST API** for Tables. So, I am fetching the record using the generated ***sys_id*** and table name which is generated as response of order API. The table name is sc_request.

But that is not providing the variable value information in the response body of the GET call.

Comment: Could you send me the code for requesting a catalog Item please. I don't seem to understand what the "Mandatory variables are defined on the associated form" are.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the values of variables using the Table API. If you go to the REST API explorer in ServiceNow, notice the field "sysparm_fields". put the name of your variabe(s) in there like this "variables.var_name". This will retrieve their values and display values in the response.